# Remove Dropdownlist Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working in MVC2. Here i had Employee Screen. There itself i am having a dropdown list. In that all the Employee Names will loaded. The Employee profile which i am viewing should not be loaded in the dropdown list. I should remove the particular Employee from the dropdown list. Here is my code for loading dropdown...How to do this...

```
Dictionary<string, Employee> Employee1 = new Dictionary<string, EmployeeDetails>();
       Employee1 = EmployeeProxy.GetPrimaryEmployeeList(UserIdentity.TenantID);

        List<EmployeeDetails> managerDetailsList = Employee1.Values.ToList();
        if (managerDetailsList != null && managerDetailsList.Count > 0)
        {
            managerDetailsList.Sort(delegate(EmployeeDetails p1, EmployeeDetails p2) { return p1.FirstName.CompareTo(p2.FirstName); });
        }
        foreach (EmployeeDetails employeedetails in managerDetailsList)
        {
            employeedetails.FirstName = employeedetails.FirstName + " " + employeedetails.LastName;
        }
```

Comment: i had Employee Screen. There itself i am having a dropdown list. In that all the Employee Names will loaded. The Employee profile which i am viewing should not be loaded in the dropdown list. I should remove the particular Employee from the dropdown list. Here is my code for loading dropdown...How to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RobinHood,

Simply change this line:

```
List<EmployeeDetails> managerDetailsList = Employee1.Values.ToList();
```

to:

```
List<EmployeeDetails> managerDetailsList = Employee1.Values.Where(x => x.ID != Employee1.ID).ToList();
```

assuming that such an attribute (ID) exists. Basically, what i'm saying is that from the managerDetailsList, exclude the Employee1 member (based on the assumption that Employee1.Values is IQueryable).